# ¿Te moriste o moriste?

Tags: objetos-directos

Entiendo que una oración como "Te fuiste" significa "(Tú) te fuiste (de una fiesta, etc)" y "Fuiste" se utilizaría en oraciones como "Fuiste a la casa de tu madre ayer". Pero con verbos como "morir", ¿debería decir "te moriste" o "moriste"? Ejemplo: Dos almas se encuentran en el más allá y una le dice a la otra "no me digas que moriste" o ¿debería ser "No me digas que te moriste"?
En mi opinión no puedo decir "te moriste" porque morir no es una acción que se pueda ejecutar sobre sí mismo, pero sí puedo decir "te mataste" porque sí se puede ejercer la acción de matar sobre sí mismo.
Referencias a alguna regla que lidie con esto sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede decir de ambas maneras. En el ejemplo que das me suena mejor "No me digas que te moriste". Aquí un extracto de [morir en el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=morir):

> **3**. Con el sentido normal de ‘dejar de vivir’, se usa tanto en forma pronominal como no pronominal, y puede llevar un complemento con *de*, que expresa la causa de la muerte: *«Mariana se murió DE una cosa difícil de precisar»* (Aguilar Error [Méx. 1995]); *«Carlos murió el mes pasado»* (Corrieri Fuera [Cuba 1978]); solo si la muerte es violenta y ha sido provocada por un agente externo, no admite el uso pronominal: *«Un muchacho de catorce años ha muerto en Pamplona, abatido también por la violencia etarra»* (Abc [Esp.] 3.6.85).

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo de oración cuasi-refleja. No es realmente reflexiva porque, como dices, no es una acción ejercida sobre el propio agente, pero se usa igualmente la construcción reflexiva. Hay muchos ejemplos en español (caerse, sentarse, pasmarse...). El enlace que da rsanchez en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8397/te-moriste-o-moriste/8398#8398) explica perfectamente el uso en este caso particular.